# Sharing cookies across apps in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, ios9

I've heard that it's possible to share cookies(obviously from the same source) across apps in `iOS9` using `SFSafariViewController`. How do I do that?

I know that loading a webpage with `SFSafariViewController` would send all of my cookies associated with it in Safari to my server which can then respond with some new cookies.

But how do I read these new cookies? They are being stored in Safari's cookie storage which is independent of any app.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate it with **url scheme** to archevie your goal.